# informatica repository Backup Failed using pmrep command

Tags: backup, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I got the error below when i'm runnig the following command  :

```
[infadm@etlserver ~]$pmrep backup -o /Prodproject/Backup/bkp_RepProd_$(date +"%Y%m%d").rep -d Desc_bkp_RepProd -f -b -j -q -v
```

[image]

any support please !!

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re finding unclear about the error message: you don’t have the required privileges to run the backup

Comment: Hi @NickW, thanks for your reply, but I runned the command after connecting by the Admin user which has the manage services privileges

Comment: So there are two possibilities: 1) the error message is incorrect and it’s not a privileges issue, in which case there’s not enough information for anyone to help you 2) the error message is correct and you’re not running the command with the user you think you are and/or that user doesn’t have the privileges you think it does

Comment: here is more information, the repository started by an unix user and not from the consol using the Admin user,  however, I'm trying the backuo the repository connecting to Admin user, is that can be the root cause of the problem ? if it is, how can do the backup ?